# Add image title and/or description to the caption

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to manipulate the output of the image captions within *the_content* in such a way that not only the caption, but also the image title and/or description (defined in the media library) are output under each image?

[image: I want to use the Data from Alt, Title, Caption AND Description in my Output]

Possibly via the functions.php?

Comment: do you have an example of the output now?

Comment: Sure. Images placed in _the_content_ are like

`<div class="wp-block-image"><figure class="alignleft size-large is-resized"><img src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/winter.jpg" alt="Correct Alt Text" width="400"></figure></div>`

Comment: Thanks what is your desired output?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to manipulate the form in which images are displayed within "the_content". For example as a <figure> including <figcaption>. Then I would like to output not only the defined caption itself, but also the image title / image description (defined in the WP Media Gallery also).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to manipulate the  on `the_content`.

The easiest way which it looks like you are wanting to do is add a filter in your functions.php file.

I just pulled this from the Codex and modified a bit so you can get the gist of what I'm talking about.

```
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'my_img_caption_shortcode', 10, 3 );
 
function my_img_caption_shortcode( $output, $attr, $content ) {
    $attr = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'      => '',
        'align'   => 'alignnone',
        'width'   => '',
        'caption' => ''
    ), $attr );
 
    if ( 1 > (int) $attr['width'] || empty( $attr['caption'] ) ) {
        return '';
    }
 
    if ( $attr['id'] ) {
        $attr['id'] = 'id="' . esc_attr( $attr['id'] ) . '" ';
    }
 
    return '<div ' . $attr['id']
    . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr( $attr['align'] ) . '" '
    . 'style="max-width: ' . ( 10 + (int) $attr['width'] ) . 'px;">'
    . do_shortcode( $content )
    . '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . $attr['caption'] . '</p>'
    . '</div>';
 
}
```

What you can then do is if you see the `$attr['caption']`, you can modify how you would like it to be. So you can do: `get_the_title($attr['id'])` to add the title or `get_post_meta($attr['id'], '_wp_attachment_image_alt', TRUE);` to get the image alt.

To make things easier if you want to grab all the details on a specific attachment you can use a function like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125554/get-image-description) and then get whatever you want.

Here's an example of adding the title to your caption. The format is "Title - Caption"

```
. '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . get_the_title($attr['id']) . " - " . $attr['caption'] . '</p>'
```

Link to Code reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/img_caption_shortcode/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm not understanding your question but it seems to me that you're using the Gutenberg editor?
... All the features you're looking for are already built-in.

If you want to set the `alt=""` or `title=""` attributes you can do it on the right side action column, by clicking on the image itself, while in the Gutenberg editor.

[image] [image]

For the `figcaption`, you can set it right under the image, by clicking on the image itself, while in the Gutenberg editor.

Comment: I've updated my question so that it's a little better understandable. Yes, I use the block editor, but I not only want to output ALT and CAPTION, but also TITLE and DESCRIPTION of the image (defined in the Media Library)

Comment: instead of the one you're defining usually in the editor ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use functions.php to determine how images should be output in "the_content". The theme is self developed.